# Spark standalone : SparklyR : Performance issues

Tags: performance, apache-spark, machine-learning, sparklyr

I'm trying to run machine learning algorithms from SparklyR library on my Spark server.

- 1 cluster
- 8 cores
- 24G RAM
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Spark 2.2
- Standalone configuration
- 1 Master/2 Workers
- Memory per Executor :4G
- 8 Cores/Worker
- 4096 Memory by Worker

In practice, I test ml_decision_tree on a very small dataset (72 x 100).
I first read locally my original dataset (72 x 7350) from a CSV file in R (read.csv), perform reshaping, and then, load the result (df_fin) in Spark (I run the code directly on the cluster where Spark is installed) :

```
df_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc,df_fin)
```

I can see my newly created RDD in server UI; its "Size in memory" is 49.9 KB, and "Size on Disk" is null. On heap memory usage, I can see : 49.9 KB (2004.6 MB Remaining).

Then, my app is stuck at running ml_decision_tree.
I have no error message in my console, my app state is "RUNNING" and the following is still written in my worker logs :

```
17/08/23 15:35:32 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 200 blocks
17/08/23 15:35:32 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
17/08/23 15:35:32 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 26 non-empty blocks out of 200 blocks
17/08/23 15:35:32 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 1 remote fetches in 1 ms
17/08/23 15:35:32 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 494.0 (TID 39532). 3082 bytes result sent to driver
17/08/23 15:35:32 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 494.0 (TID 39531). 4073 bytes result sent to driver ...
```

Then 35 minutes later, at console : "*No rows dropped by 'na.omit' call"
meaning that things are moving ahead..

So it still doing something, but I can't understand what. When I run the same code locally in my RShiny on my own computer, process finishes quite quick (3 or 4 minutes). Finally, my process ends after +/- 50 minutes with the following error :

> Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I guess this Java error comes from the garbage collector using a big part of my CPU ressources, without free lot's of memory... But where does it come from ?

I guess I missed something in my Spark understanding; normally Spark should fast the processes, but in my case it is worst. I can't imaging dealing with huge datasets that way.

Also, I would like to load in Spark my original dataframe (72 x 7350) to perform machine learning on it (when my slowness issue will be solved indeed...) .

What's the best way to do ? Use spark_read_csv ? I do not use HDFS. I considered that I will not have enough data to exploit Hadoop abilities (some Tb, not more).

When I tried to load the original dataframe, I got this error :

> Caused by: org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: Constant pool for class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection has grown past JVM limit of 0xFFFF

I saw on SPARK-18016 [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18016) than

> "We fixed a problem for the large number (e.g. 4000) of columns. However, we know that we have not solved a problem for the very large number (e.g. 12000) of columns."

I do not really understand. Spark has been designed for Big Data, why should it fail with (in my case) 7350 colmuns ?

Can someone guide me about this issue ? Does it come from my stettings ? Should I add more workers ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

> I do not really understand. Spark has been designed for Big Data, why should it fail with (in my case) 7350 colmuns ?

Not all "big data" is equal and different design choices are made depending on the shape of the data (wide, long, both). Most of the time systems focus on long and thin datasets. This is the case with Spark.

The problem here is not amount of data but complexity of the optimizer. In Spark ML this is not a big problem since Spark uses `Vector` types to combine features, and if that's not enough, it is always possible to use low level API. `sparklyr` however, made unfortunate decision to expand transformed features -  this is something that cannot work well.

> 72 x 7350

It doesn't make sense to use Spark with data like this. If you can run:

```
df_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc,df_fin)
```

it means that data fits in the memory and there is no need for distributed processing.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for your answer. I would like some precisions however; what do you mean when you say that sparklyr makes unfortunate decisions ? Do you mean that my code would work better if I'd implement it in Python or directly in Scala ? Also, I wanted to use Spark because I will have to process a lot of dataframes like this in a near futur (clinical data, meaning lot's of wide data, but also imaging data, to perform deep learning on); this is why I guessed that Spark could be a useful solution ? What's your opinion regarding this ?